# Prevent Excel Microsoft Visual Basic for Application from deleting space

Tags: excel, vba

Every time I hit space to write the next keyword, it just deletes the space, and ends concatenating the two existing keyword with the new typed keyword, unless I type very fast, which we all can but it's ridiculous.

How can I disable this behavior?

I tried Options>Editor>Coding Settings, unchecked both Auto Syntax Check and Require Variable Declaration. Neither seem to matter.

i.e.

If I try to type

```
If a > ..
```

If I wait too long before typing `a` it goes back to

```
 If
```

Comment: What "keywords" are you typing?

Comment: Doesn't do that for me - I have had my VBE sitting there saying `If ` for a couple of minutes now, with no attempt by the IDE to get rid of the trailing space.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Visual Basic for Application, that comes with Excel 2013 on Windows

Comment: Exactly the same environment as me. Do you possibly have some Excel Add-in that is doing something weird (try disabling all add-ins and see if the problem persists) or even some other, non-Excel, application that is doing it.

Comment: FWIW, I am seeing the behaviour now, but it is on a veeeeery long timeout period (more than 10 minutes) and I am pretty certain it is to do with doing something in another application.  Hmm, it triggered again just then, while I was typing this comment.  (Note: I wasn't in design mode when it triggered.)

Comment: Also FWIW - I just let my computer sit without me touching it (apart from "waving" the mouse every now and then to stop it locking) and it removed the space after the `If` after about 12 minutes.  Another time it did it after about 5 minutes.  So it seems like there must be some sort of background process involved rather than a specific "timeout" interval.

Comment: @YowE3K Issue doesn't occur at my other laptop with Microsoft Excel 365, and Visual Basic 7.1. Only when I click away it removes space. In the windows case, I just add a space, and it within a second removes it (without clicking out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it... Exit design mode prevents it from happening.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't do it for me whether I am in design mode or have exited design mode.

Comment: @YowE3K, weird... another colleague here experienced the same behavior and resolution. I'll check it later today on another laptop

Comment: It may be that the "Exit Design Mode" terminates something else that you were doing (not sure what) which therefore means that my test of simply being in, or not in, design mode did not cause the issue.  (I.e. exiting design mode fixes the problem, but simply being in design mode is not the cause of the problem.)